# If a variable = this, then do this

Tags: c#, variables, random, numbers

I'm new to coding with C# and I've looked around for an answer but none really make sense to me, I'm trying to set a variable to a random number, and if it equals 1, do this, if it equals 2, do this. Thanks

Code:

```
if (goright == true)
            {
                Random rand = new Random();
                var x = rand.Next(1, 8);

                     if x = 1 ;
                    {
                        makeBullet2();
                        makeBullet3();
                        makeBullet4();
                    }
```

Comment: you may try swich-case

Comment: As you are new to C#, Google might help you better! Like you could google this `c# conditional statements` for your current issue.

Answer (score 0):

You either want if/else if:

```
if (x == 1)
{
    makeBullet1();
}
else if (x == 2)
{
    makeBullet2();
}
else
{
    // you can also include "else" without an "if" statement if you want a generic action to happen if none of the other cases are matched
}
```

or you could use `switch`:

```
switch (x)
{
    case 1:
        makeBullet1();
        break;
    case 2:
        makeBullet2();
        break;
    default:
        // similar to else
        break;
}
```

If you find yourself having to check a lot of single values (e.g. x==1, x==..., x==n) then a switch statement is probably better. If you have complicated logic (x > 1 && x < 5 && y = 42 && !sunday) then an if statement is better.

Comment: If performance is ever a concern when choosing between these two, I have benchmarked switch statements as being _slightly_ faster in the past.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, you can use `Switch` statement like below :

```
Random rand = new Random();
var x = rand.Next(1, 8);

switch (x)
{
    case 1:
        makeBullet1();
        break;
    case 2:
        makeBullet2();
        break;
    case 3:
        makeBullet3();
        break;
    case 4:
        makeBullet4();
        break;
    default:
        // your code if no case was true
        break;          
}
```